# How to find out what driver the Ethernet NIC is using?

Tags: 12.04, networking, ethernet, nic

I have a 10Gbps Ethernet NIC on my Ubuntu box which is named `eth0`. Is there any way to find out which driver is loaded to work with this NIC?

Comment: Can also look at `lspci -knn | grep -A2 Net`

Comment: @meccooll : No output. I think you should use _Ethernet_ instead of _Net_ . Unfortunately this command doesn't show interface name, so i should find the driver by matching BUS address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `ethtool -i` outputs hardware info about the NIC. Use following command to see driver name:

```
ethtool -i eth0 | grep driver
```

The output is like this:

```
driver: e1000
```

Comment: Is your NIC a 10Gbps one?

Comment: No. I'm using `E1000` of ESXi. It's 1Gbps.